# Saber cual boton se dio click en submit jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy haciendo una petición ajax con jquery, en mi formulario tengo dos botones para hacer el submit uno de solo guardar y otro de enviar y terminar todo, actualmente utilizo dos funciones de jquery on click para cada boton por separado, pero me gustaría poder hacer un on submit para los dos botones.

El problema viene cuando necesito saber en el on submit que boton estoy apretando, no encuentro la forma para hacerlo.

```
$("#save").on('submit',(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var formString = new FormData($("#preview")[0]);

//Aqui necesito cambiar el estatus dependiendo de cual boton se dio click
formString.append('status', 'IP');

$("#save").prop('disabled', false);
$("#make").prop('disabled', false);

$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo URL ?>"+"items/emp_make",
  type: "POST",
  data:  formString,
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    $("#save").prop('disabled', false);
    $("#make").prop('disabled', false);
    if (data.status == true) {
      swal({
          position: 'top-end',
          type: 'success',
          title: data.msn,
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 1500,
          customClass: 'content-header-center'
        });
      setTimeout(function(){
          window.location.replace("<?php echo URL ?>ver/"+data.id);
        }, 1900);
    }
  },
  error: function(data){
    console.log(data)
    console.error('error');
  }
});
}));
```

Comment: tus dos botones tienen el mismo id?

Comment: No tienen diferente, uno es save y el otro es make

Comment: al inicio de tu código tienes esto `$("#save").on(...)`, con eso solo estás capturando el submit del boton con id save

Comment: Aun poniendo el id del submit que es $("#emp").on('submit') no me dice como saber que boton se dió click.

Comment: a que te refieres con que no sabes, el evento lo estas asociando a ese boton, si ese código se ejecuta es porque ese boton se presionó

Comment: El id del formulario es "emp", asociando el evento de submit con ese id no se como saber cual boton se presiono.

Answer (score 1):

Uno de tus problemas es que estás llamando el .on('submit') en el botón save, el .on('submit') debes asignárselo al id de tu formulario o directamente a la etiqueta "form", sería algo como esto:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <button type="submit" class="myFormButton" name="save">Save</button>
  <button type="submit" class="myFormButton" name="make">Update</button>
</form>
```

Por otro lado, necesitarías una función que maneje el click antes de hacer el submit, para que te endique qué botón fue clickeado, se lo pasas a una variable y la utilizas dentro del .on('submit')  en este caso, esto te puede funcionar:

```
$(function() {
     var buttonpressed;
    $('.myFormButton').click(function() {
          buttonpressed = $(this).attr('name')
    })
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          alert('El botón presionado fue ' + buttonpressed);
          // Aquí el resto del código
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta declarandole un atributo a cada boton donde pueda ser facilmente identificable:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  if($(this).data('destino') == 'editar'){
    alert('Editando')
  }
  else{
    alert('Guardando');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-destino="guardar">Agregar</button>
<button data-destino="editar">Editar</button>
```

En el ejemplo, se lee en atributo `data-destino` que identifica a cada boton y haces la accion correspondiente segun desees.

---

Nota: personalmente dejaria cada boton con su propio evento ya que asi no estaria rompiendo el [Principio de Responsabilidad Unica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica) y no tener que complicar el codigo al momento de hacer un cambio futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Si cuando presiones el botón de Guardar o de Actualizar se va a ejecutar la misma acción puedes perfectamente compartir un *listener*  para el click de esos dos botones. Puedes dar un `id` a cada uno, que recuperarías con `this.id` y ya sabrás qué botón fue pulsado para mandar una señal al servidor por ejemplo de si debe guardar o debe actualizar.

Puedes en ese sentido agrupar los botones en una clase (esto es particularmente útil cuando tienes más botones y no quieres que todos ejecuten las mismas acciones). O puedes también identificar los botones y agregarles el mismo *listener* (esto sería menos práctico, porque con `this` puedes identificar el botón una vez dentro de la función).

Veamos un ejemplo: tienes tres botones, dos lanzan acciones comunes y uno lanza otro tipo de acciones. Verás que reaccionan diferente debido al atributo `class` de cada uno.

```js
$("button.crud").click(function(e) {
  console.log(1);
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(`Se presionó el botón: ${this.id}`);
})

$("button.no-crud").click(function(e) {
  console.log("Ahora sí");
  console.log(`Se presionó el botón: ${this.id} pero estamos en otra función`);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSave" class="crud">Agregar</button>
<button id="btnUpdate" class="crud">Editar</button>
<button id="btnOtro" class="no-crud">Este No</button>
```